# How do you make a new directory?

Tags: directory

I'm trying to create a new directory. I'm using mkdir, but for some reason it isn't working.

Are there any other ways to make directories I don't know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide more information - what is your operating system, what is the context behind this, and what is your intended result (there may be multiple ways to achieve this)

Answer (score 1):

Please be more specific, if you mean creating a new directory in CMD the correct syntax is: MKDIR dir_name

```
i.e:

C:\Users\Thunder>mkdir new_directory

C:\Users\Thunder>dir

04/12/2020  17:50    <DIR>          Music
08/12/2020  19:52    <DIR>          MyFirstGame
***22/12/2020  16:05    <DIR>          new_directory***
24/10/2020  16:11    <DIR>          Nox_share
24/10/2020  16:10                45 nuuid.ini
```

Be sure you have correct access, just in case run CMD as administrator.